# An error occurred loading the Yoast SEO primary taxonomy picker

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, yoast

I am facing this error in edit post page from custom post type in admin side. Also i am getting one error in console "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPrimaryTaxonomyId' of undefined" from react-dom.min.js file from WordPress include js folder. So can you please help me to resolve this issue or suggest me way that how can i overcome from this problem.

I have solution from below github link:
https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/13032

I want just remove this error: "An error occurred loading the Yoast SEO primary taxonomy picker."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add below line in functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_primary_term_taxonomies', '__return_empty_array' );
```